# SQL ExecuteScalar doesn't throw exception when insert used with output clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exception

I came across an interesting issue with the "ExecuteScalar()" method of the SqlCommand object.

I have a stored procedure, which creates a new record in a table. It contains an "insert" statement which has an "output" clause *(as the created record utilises an identity column and some default values)*.

This works fine, and the "ExecuteScalar" returns the identity column value *(1st row, 1st column)*.

However, in testing, I deliberately call my stored procedure twice, and on the second time it is expected to hit a unique constraint in the data table and fail *(there's a "try/catch/throw" in the SP)*.

So far so good, except the 2nd call returns an empty rowset *(as I can verify if I run this from SQLMgr)* and ExecuteScalar returns a null - **but** doesn't throw the exception.

This isn't what was expected and leaves me with an interesting question. How can I utilise ExecuteScalar - in order to, in a success scenario, return the id column value - but have it fail should an error occur ?

I know that if I remove the "output" clause from my "insert", the exception is thrown as would be expected.

If this is expected behaviour, how should I call my SP, in order to return the id value, and have the exception raised should my constraint be hit ?

Obviously, I could do all manner of jiggery-pokery in the stored procedure *(like insert then select using scope_identity)*, and - as I have done in my tests - I could check for a null return and make a subsequent ExecuteNonQuery call *(which does throw the exception)*. But that all seems a bit of a fudge, given the usefulness of the "output" clause.

I have done some "Googling", and have found a reference to ExecuteScalar "eating" exceptions, but it was only a passing reference.

Ideas ?

**-- edit 1 --**

What I'm saying, upon further investigation writing the "simple case" below, is that (apparently) if I have a stored procedure, which has a "try catch", and an insert which violates a unique constraint, when invoked via ExecuteScalar, I do not get an exception.

- If I remove the "try/catch/throw" - I get the exception.
- If I remove the "output" - I get the exception

**-- edit 2 --**

Here are some samples (and this is *very* cut down... and yes, I use the "try/catch" to skip other functionality:

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_test_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UNQ_test_description] ON [dbo].[test]([description] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

SP looks like this:

```
create procedure dbo.fred
(
    @Code           varchar(10),
    @Description    varchar(100)
)
as
begin
    begin try

        insert into dbo.test
            (value, [description])
        output
            inserted.ID
        values
            (@Code, @Description)

    end try
    begin catch
        throw
    end catch
end
```

Comment: Try adding a minimal example that compiles the issue you're seeing. The easier you make checking this for everyone, the faster you'll get help :)

Comment: Are you saying that you execute the same proc twice in a single ExecuteScalar method?  Note that ExecuteScalar ignores all but the first column of the first resultset.  The implication is that this will eat subsequent exceptions that are after the statement that returned the scalar value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from Dan's suggestion, I wrote a strongly-typed extension method which, while not a direct replacement for ExecuteScalar(), is close enough for my needs.

The main two bonus points from this extension are that the resulting scalar value is strongly typed, and, should an exception have occurred in the execution of the command - resulting in either some or no data - all results are traversed over in order to detect the exception. One downside is that the scalar result might not now be null if no result was returned *(because the generic type might not be nullable (ie. Int32))*.

In my case, this is fine, because I'm either going to get a result, or I'm going to get an exception. What I'm not going to get *(through design)* is a single value, in the first row of a massive resultset, followed by an exception. If we take it that ExecuteScalar is only supposed to be interested in the first column of the first row, my extension will *(I suspect)* force a traversal of all the results *(which could be quite large)* until either all data is read and/or an exception is encountered. If you're not expecting that, the performance impact may be of concern. In my case, I'm inserting a row and returning that row, from which I take the first column.

Not perfect, but the point I was addressing was that if a command raises an exception, I want to know - regardless of whether it had already decided upon the results to be returned.

I list the extension in case its of use:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is here because SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() can, under some circumstances, fail to propagate an exception raised by the command.
    /// </remarks>
    static public T ExecuteScalar<T>(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                var value = reader.GetValue(0);

                try
                {
                    result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new FormatException(String.Format("Unable to convert scalar value of \"{0}\" to type {1}.", value, typeof(T)),ex);
                }
            }

            while (reader.NextResult()) ;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row and discards the remaining results, which could include exceptions.  In the case of the `OUTPUT` clause, an error on the `INSERT`, and a SQL TRY/CATCH, the empty single-column result is returned first followed by the discarded exception.

You can use the ExecuteReader method directly if you want more control.  ExecuteScalar and its ExecuteNonQuery cousin are basically just wrappers around ExecuteReader anyway.

```
var r = command.ExecuteReader();
if (r.Read())
    result = r.GetInt32(0);
else
    r.NextResult();
r.Close();
```

Comment: Interesting that it would discard the exception when, given that the insert has failed, the exception is more relevant than the empty results. I'm struggling to see how, given the above, and no knowledge of how a target SP is written, ExecuteScalar is a good choice in the scenario where you do an insert and want to know the 1st row/1st column value (as is often the case when that value is an identity value).

Comment: @BlackLight, I'm personally not a big fan of ExecuteScalar.  In addition to the `OUTPUT` clause issue you ran into here, the return value isn't strongly-typed.  The underlying issue with the exception is that results are returned using the streaming TDS protocol.  The exception is behind the result but ExecuteScalar discards everything but the first row.  You could also run into this issue with a multi-statement proc where a SELECT statement precedes other DML.

Comment: Hi Dan, no, I'm not a big fan - now. I've written a generic extension which gets around the "strongly-typed" issue, and throws an exception, but haven't thought it through so that it always finds any exception. I presume that I'll have to get the 1st row/col value, and then walk through all the following results to check whether any have an extension. Not a big deal, but mildly annoying as I can't see the case when I *wouldn't* want to know about an exception. I'll post it as a reply when I have a chance to finish it (famous IT saying no 57).

Comment: Wow.  Been doing this for years, never knew this.  Not that I use ExecuteScalar that much.  Thanks.

Comment: For future readers, I found this out because of a temp/fake statement I was putting in my code.                SELECT 1/0 as PurposelyInducedError         The PurposelyInducedError was actually what ExecuteScalar saw and ignored the actual "Divide by zero error encountered." error.  I thought I was going crazy. Full sample in next comment.

Comment: CREATE Procedure dbo.uspPurposelyThrowError
AS

BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON


 BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

   SELECT 1/0 as PurposelyInducedError

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
 
  THROW; /* There is no severity parameter. The exception severity is always set to 16. */  

 END CATCH

 SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
 
GO